# Click button if exists

Tags: python, selenium

Here is my code:

```
ignore_btn_status = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body > div.ui-dialog.ui-corner-all.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-front.ui-dialog-buttons.ui-draggable.ui-resizable > div.ui-dialog-buttonpane.ui-widget-content.ui-helper-clearfix > div > button:nth-child(1)")
    if (ignore_btn_status):
        ignore_btn_status[0].click()
```

But I am getting error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-114-d9f8d3835039> in <module>
     27     #    pass
     28 
---> 29     ignore_btn_status = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body > div.ui-dialog.ui-corner-all.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-front.ui-dialog-buttons.ui-draggable.ui-resizable > div.ui-dialog-buttonpane.ui-widget-content.ui-helper-clearfix > div > button:nth-child(1)")
     30     if (ignore_btn_status):
     31         ignore_btn_status[0].click

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in find_element_by_css_selector(self, css_selector)
    596             element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#foo')
    597         """
--> 598         return self.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)
    599 
    600     def find_elements_by_css_selector(self, css_selector):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in find_element(self, by, value)
    976         return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
    977             'using': by,
--> 978             'value': value})['value']
    979 
    980     def find_elements(self, by=By.ID, value=None):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"body > div.ui-dialog.ui-corner-all.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-front.ui-dialog-buttons.ui-draggable.ui-resizable > div.ui-dialog-buttonpane.ui-widget-content.ui-helper-clearfix > div > button:nth-child(1)"}
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.138)
```

**Question:** How to fix my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the find element method throws an exception when the element is not found. You can catch the exception like this:

```
   try:
      ignore_btn_status = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body > div.ui-dialog.ui-corner-all.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-front.ui-dialog-buttons.ui-draggable.ui-resizable > div.ui-dialog-buttonpane.ui-widget-content.ui-helper-clearfix > div > button:nth-child(1)")
      ignore_btn_status.click()
    except:
      print("Button not found")
```

To be more specific you can catch the NoSuchElementException. For more information see here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Answer (score 1):

Just put it inside a try except:

```
        try:
          ignore_btn_status = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body > div.ui-dialog.ui-corner-all.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-front.ui-dialog-buttons.ui-draggable.ui-resizable > div.ui-dialog-buttonpane.ui-widget-content.ui-helper-clearfix > div > button:nth-child(1)")
          ignore_btn_status.click()

        except:
          print("does not exist")
```

Also not that I removed the [0], because you did 'find_element' and not 'find_elements'